# If $\alpha$ is an n-cycle, then $\alpha^k$ is a product of $(n,k)$ disjoint cycles, each of length $n/(n,k)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

If $\alpha$ is an n-cycle, then $\alpha^k$ is a product of $(n,k)$ disjoint cycles, each of length $n/(n,k)$

What I tried is let $a_i$ be an element of the cycle and $l$ be length of each disjoint cycles. 
Then $$a_{i+lk}=a_i$$
which means that $i+lk\equiv i$ and hence $lk\equiv n$ where $l$ is the smallest positive integer satisfying this equation.
So how can I show that $$l=n/(n,k)$$

Comment: I happened on this problem in Rotman. What is the justification for saying $l$ is the smallest positive integer satisfying the equation?

Comment: Justification for anyone wondering: The smallest integer $k$ such that $\alpha^k=1$ where $\alpha$ is the product of disjoint cycles is the least common multiple of the cycle lengths. I did the first 12 exercises a few weeks ago and completely forgot about them; the justification relies on 1.12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. If $l$ is the smallest integer such that $lk$ is a multiple of $n$, then $lk = \text{lcm}(k,n)$. But $\text{lcm}(k,n) = nk/\gcd(n,k)$.

Answer (score 1):

Lemma: Let $a$ be an element of a group $G$ such that $|a|=n>0$. Hence $|a^k|=\frac{n}{(n,k)}$.
Write $d:=(n,k)$ and consider $0<q_1,q_2\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $dq_1=k$ and $dq_2=n$. So we have $(a^k)^{q_2}=a^{kq_2}=a^{q_1n}=1$. If $t\in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ is such that $t<q_2$  then it can not be $(a^k)^t=1$ because $d=xk+yn$ (Bezout theorem) whence $dt=x(kt)+ytn$ with $dt<n$. Therefore $|a^k|=\frac{n}{(n,k)}$.

In the initial problem we have $\alpha^k$ is a regular permutation, i.e., $\alpha^k=\beta_1 \beta_2\ldots\beta_m$, $\beta_i$ are $l$-cycles disjoints. From of this we have $lm=n$ and $|a^k|=$ least commom multiple of $\{ l \}$. The lemma implies $l=\frac{n}{(n,k)}$. Hence $\frac{n}{(n,k)}\cdot m=n$ and therefore $m=(n,k)$.